# how to aviod soql query in the loop , i have to get get child data in my method

Tags: soql, map, before-trigger, bulkification, childrecords

I have 2 object object1 and object 2(related object) ,,,i wrote trigger on  object1 when object 1 record gets created user record should get created.. i stored profile perssion set information in object2 ... currently i am fetching the object2 data using quesry for each if and else condition inside for oop. which is not a best practise so created one method where i am  hold object2 data

```
public class myTriggerHandler{

public static void isBeforeInsert(List<Object__c> lObj)
{
    myTriggerHandler.manageInsert(lObj);
}

public static void manageInsert(List<Object__c> lObj){

    set<id> setlookup = new set<id>();
    for(Object__ o : lObj){
        setlookup.add(o.Obj2__c);
    }

    //query data from object 2 as relationship data is not available inside trigger.
    Map<id,Obj2__c> maplookupObject =  new Map<id,Obj2__c>([select id,StartDate__c from obj2__c where id in : setlookup]); // Edited

    System.debug('### lObj : ' + lObj); //null in logs
   string profile;
string role;
    for(Object__ o : lObj){
        //access data here from map collection.
       Profile = maplookupObject.get(o.Obj2__c).ProfileName__c;
     Role =     maplookupObject.get(o.Obj2__c).RoleName__c;
    }
}
```

When i am calling this method  in my main method which is to create user record i am getting

> Error: Invalid Data. 
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger User caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator

error message is givving line no where i am fetching profile name from the map....It will be great if someone can help me how i can i avoid soql inside loop..and how i can call my child data method in my method ? how i can access child data in my main class

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for `null` values. Here:

```
 Profile = maplookupObject.get(o.Obj2__c).ProfileName__c;
 Role =     maplookupObject.get(o.Obj2__c).RoleName__c;
```

if `o.Obj2__c` is `null`, the result of `get()` will also be `null`. You then dereference that value to obtain values, which will immediately cause a `NullPointerException`. Wrap these accesses in an `if (o.Obj2__c != null)` check first, and implement appropriate logic for if the field is `null`.

You do not appear to have SOQL in a loop at present, so I'm not sure what your concern is there. You seem to have a separate problem indicated by a comment:

```
System.debug('### lObj : ' + lObj); //null in logs
```

but you haven't shown us enough code to propose a solution there.